# display database table data in datatable in c# but the datatable is blank

Tags: c#, gridview, datatable

I have a `GridView`. I am trying to display DB table data into grid using `DataTable`. So I am saving the query result in `DataTable`, but the data is not displayed. Here is my code. Please help.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {        
        DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
        string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["gridconnection"].ConnectionString;

        string query = "select * from GridExcel";

        SqlConnection con1 = new SqlConnection(constr);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con1);
        con1.Open();

        // create data adapter
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        // this will query your database and return the result to your 
        datatable
        da.Fill(dataTable);
        Gridview1.DataSource = dataTable;
        Gridview1.DataBind();
        ViewState["CurrentTable"] = dataTable;
        con1.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: con.Open(); or con1.Open()?

Comment: Does `select * from GridExcel` return anything?

Comment: `SqlDataAdapter` doesn't  need open connection

Comment: At least compile you code once and make sure the code in your post are without any compile time errors

Comment: @SureshPrajapati I didnt got any compile time error

Comment: @nirmala I think calling function `Open()` on object `con` should throw a compile time error as object `con` don't seems to be created. Please correct me if I am missing something.

Comment: @SureshPrajapati no actually here in question I did a mistake but in code its is con1 only. So there is no issue with con.

Comment: Have you changed anything within grid?

Comment: I forgot to add "Text='<%# Bind("Column1") %>'" in itemtemplate. My problem has been solved. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try to use a DataReader:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if (!IsPostBack)
  {

    DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
    string constr =      ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["gridconnection"].ConnectionString;

    string query = "select * from GridExcel";

    SqlConnection con1 = new SqlConnection(constr);
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con1);
    con1.Open();

    // create data adapter
    SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    // this will query your database and return the result to your datatable
    dataTable.Load(reader);
    Gridview1.DataSource = dataTable;
    Gridview1.DataBind();
    ViewState["CurrentTable"] = dataTable;
    con1.Close();
  }
}
```

Comment: No one asked me for explanation/clarification there, here I feel doubt why reader do the job where adapter fails, that's why I asked for clarification. If you need clarification for any of my post means fee free to ask either as a comment or through mails.

Comment: I'm not interested in arguments, and taking personal revenges, kindly ignore my comment(let me delete that as well). sorry for wasting the time

Comment: For clarification: From what I understand, The SqlDataAdapter fills a table if the columns are allready present there (https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/905keexk(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @RomanoZumbé the result of my code and your code is same. it displays first column data but remaining column data is not displayed.

Answer (score 0):

The below code is works for me.

```
string constring = @"Data Source=.\SQL2005;Initial Catalog=gridconnection;";
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constring))
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from GridExcel", con))
        {
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
            {
                using (DataTable dt = new DataTable())
                {
                    da.Fill(dt);
                    dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```